# query stopped working after importrange

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script

Stack overflow Question:

I'm  a beginner at Google Sheets, so please bear with me. I have a  google spreadsheet with five sheets, four of which are reports, each of which is generated by a Query fetching info from the fifth sheet (within the same spreadsheet) called "rawdata".  "Rawdata" has field names in columns A thru AE and data in 1700 rows of data A2:AE1700.

A sample query on one of the sheets producing a nice report is: 
**=unique(query(rawdata!A:AE, "select A,B,D,E,F,G,H,I,K,L,M,O,P,Q,C,Z where I <> '' order by A, M", 1))**

**Everything works great!  No problem.**  That query (and the similar queries for the other four query sheets) produces the exact report(s) we want, all based on the data in "rawdata".

**However I have  a need to periodically refresh all the data in the "rawdata" sheet.**   That new data comes from a new file called latest_vehicles.xlsx generated each night and placed in my Google Sheets as a Google sheet (not just a read only file).

That file contains all the fresh data. I realized that new file, while having the same name, will have a new "KEY".  But with benefit of opening that new file, I can copy the new KEY of that new file then paste it into a new IMPORTRAGE function.  After deleting everything from "rawdata'' (A1:AE1700)  I then insert the newly edited IMPORTRAGE function (shown below) into cell A1 of the rawdata sheet

=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UAnj3vKIjnVKirZEUt6gi3MlcbJ9NYFLSX2-dEcTqlc/edit#gid=1864706911","sheet1!A1:AE1700")

**BINGO, it duly generates all new data in "rawdata."    How very cool.**  I now think I'm home free.

But now the kicker and my question for you gurus.  **Even though "rawdata" now contains all new data, when looking at the four report sheets, the queries which reference "Rawdata" no longer produce any data.**  The queries do populate field names (row 1), but no data follows.  What's holding things up?

I know the queries are working (Well, sort of) because if one of the field names in row 1 following the embedded query in cell A1 is deleted, it is quickly repopulated as you'd expect the query to do.  But no data follows.  Just field names.

Putting aside the nasty problem of having to research and edit changing KEY  for the IMPORTRANGE function (I'll deal with that later) Why, when data is completely refreshed (by the IMPORTRANGE function) in "rawdata" sheet, do the queries breakdown and stop providing data, only providing field names?

I do plan on scripting all this to be an automated on Open() process, but not until I can make it happen manually.

**Any thoughts/suggestions are most welcome.**

Comment: Sorry, First time user.  Don't know why it's "Read Only" posting or how to fix that. Sorry.  I'll continue looking. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: I hope that you realize that by referring to a page with the names "Rawdata" and "rawdata' that those are two different pages.

Comment: Thanks Cooper.  But those are jst typos in my narrative.  In my workbook (sorry, spreadsheet) the tab (sorry sheet) is titled in lowercase, "rawdata, "  and all the queries read "rawdata".  Great thought, however.